# Return value from addEventListener function

Tags: html, video, return, addeventlistener, duration

```
function getVideoDuration() {

    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function {
        var duration = (Math.round(myVideo.duration));
        return duration;
    });
}
```

I will be simple and direct...

I want to get out the duration value of the function inside add.EventListener. However this is not working as expected, and I think it's not possible...

Am I right? If so, what kinda of alternatives do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it the way you're trying to do it.  The `loadedmetadata` event happens some time in the future.  It doesn't happen when `getVideoDuration()` is called.  Instead, you need to put any code that needs the duration IN the eventlistener where the duration is retrieved or call a function from there and pass it the duration value.

Here's a break-down of the sequencing in your code:

1. You call `getVideoDuration()`
2. You get the first `<video>` tag.
3. You add an event listener to it for the `loadedmetadata` event.
4. Your `getVideoDuration()` function completes and exits and returns nothing.
5. Then, some time later, the `loadedmetadata` event occurs on that video tag and your event handler is called.  You fetch the duration and return it back into the event system (e.g. it goes nowhere and is not used by any code).

Here's one way you can do it:

```
function getVideoDuration() {

    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function {
        var duration = (Math.round(myVideo.duration));
        // call a function that needs the duration
        myFunction(duration);
    });
}
```

Comment: @zppinto - see the code example I have already added to my answer.

Comment: Hum... So that's why I can't use that approach! I already suspect of it! Thank you for your help :)